# Работа с частью изображения

Tags: delphi, graphics

Хочу добиться такого эффекта:

http://s40.radikal.ru/i089/1409/2a/99a617bef06a.jpg

Как работать с конкретной частью изображения?

Comment: @pmipmi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для BMP в два клика гуглится такой проект:

http://delphiexpert.ru/negativ-i-gradiet-serogo-iz-foto-delphi-isxodnik.html

Проходим по координатам по каждому пикселю в выделенной области и меняем R на 255-R, G - на 255-G, B - на 255-B.